# Rails AuthLogic Session add attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I am using Rails Authlogic, and I need to store additional data in the `UserSession` object.

As said [here](http://railsblog.kieser.net/2010/03/authlogic-custom-logins-and-persisting.html), it should be possible to add `attr_accessor` to the model and it'll be saved.

So here's my model:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base  
  attr_accessor :permissions

  before_save :set_permissions

  def set_permissions
    self.permissions = ["permissions"]
  end

end
```

I can debug and see that `set_permissions` really gets called before creating the session.
But when I do

```
@current_auth_session ||= UserSession.find
@permissions = @current_auth_session.permissions
```

`@permissions` is always nil.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you storing your UserSession data in a cookie or in a DB?  If you are storing in a cookie, setting permissions in this way would seem dangerous / risky.

Comment: Also, have you considered using Rails' own "session"?